# What Python syntax rule allows a space between a period and method call?

Tags: python

I noticed an error in some python code.  I expected it to fail, but it runs just fine.  In essence the code is:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method(self):
        print("in method")

a = Foo()
a.method()
a. method()
```

The space between `a.` and `method()` is what I'm curious about.  Both calls work just fine.  Why is this?  Is the behavior of this syntax undefined, if not, what rule does it follow?

Using Python 3. 5.2

Comment: Even `a . method()` will work. In fact, any arbitrary number of whitespaces is allowed before and after the dot.